# Delete reference via appsscript between G Spreadsheets G Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im working on a project where I want to save spreadsheet files as PDF, befor that I need to copy the file in a temporary and delete the redundant sheets.

The problem is that one sheet refer to a formular which makes the script unable to delet the redundant sheet.

It is possible to delete the reference manually.

I want to that with appsscipt.

Recently I cant find a way to do this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#removedestination

Comment: Thank you for the answere, I test the command "removeDestination();" it seams that it does not work in spreadsheets. Maybe I do something wrong.  Do I have to Implement the form object first in my script?

Comment: You have to call it on the Form, not the spreadsheet. `FormApp.openById(ID).removeDestination()`

Comment: thats not gonna work because i neet the reference for the main sheet, I just want do delete it for the tempoary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [Spreadsheet.copy(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copyname), the spreadsheet is copied along with (most) of its metadata, including the Forms binding. In order to avoid this, you can create your own `copy` function that copies it sheet-by-sheet, avoiding preserving the binding. The function would look like:

```js
function customCopy(origin, destination) {
  origin.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    var copiedSheet = sheet.copyTo(destination);
    copiedSheet.setName(sheet.getName());
  });

  destination.deleteSheet(destination.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

And you can test it using the function:

```js
function test() {
  var origin = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.create('New Spreadsheet');
  customCopy(origin, destination);
}
```

Note that this alternative function will be considerably slower than Spreadsheet.copy, especially if your Spreadsheets documents contain many Sheets.